# Windows: [WinError 126] specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to compile a .py file on Windows (PowerShell) and I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\User\TESI_M\CODICI\SETTORI_ESTR_unico> python3 nest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nest.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bicm import BipartiteGraph
  File "C:\Users\User\TESI_M\CODICI\SETTORI_ESTR_unico\bicm\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .network_functions import *
  File "C:\Users\User\TESI_M\CODICI\SETTORI_ESTR_unico\bicm\network_functions.py", line 6, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato
```

(the last line can be traslated as 'specified module could not be found').

On Mac I don't have any problems and it works fine also when I compile it on Windows using jupyter notebook.
What could I do to solve the problem?